# Jquery animation hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my website i have an image that when hover it goes up using this.

HTML

```
<div class="first">
<a href="#dialogdemo" name="modal"><img src="images/1sticon.png" alt=" " border="0"/></a>
    <div class="support">
    <img src="images/orpan.png" alt=" " />
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
 $('.first img').hover(
   function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({marginTop:'-25px',}, 300);  
   },
   function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({marginTop:'0px',}, 300);
   }
);
```

but i have another image at the back of it that when hover i want the image above it to stay on its place and when mouseout it the 1st image above will go down to cover the image under it (back image).

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand fully what your requirement is but I think you can use .live() of jquery to achieve what you want

```
$('.support1 img').live('mouseenter',function(){
    "your code"
}).live('mouseleave',function(){
    "your code"
});
```

Comment: sorry if you didn't understand it.its just merely an image hover that goes up and under it is another image that when hover the 1st image that is above stays up.. it only goes down then its mouseout